# Identificar multiples ckeditor5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Tengo dos ckeditor5 en un formulario (`qte_presentation` y `qte_terms`), los defino asi:

```
ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector('#qte_presentation'), {
    toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote', 'unDo', 'reDo' ]
} )

.then( editor => {
    window.editor = editor;
} )

.catch( err => {
    alertify.error( err.stack );
} );

ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector('#qte_terms'), {
    toolbar: [ 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote', 'unDo', 'reDo' ]
} )

.then( editor => {
    window.editor = editor;
} )

.catch( err => {
    alertify.error( err.stack );
} );
```

Necesito darles un valor y trato de hacerlo con las propiedades `val` o `text` y ninguma funciona:

```
    $("#qte_presentation").val(e.params.data.qte_presentation);
    $("#qte_terms").val(e.params.data.qte_terms);
```

con la instruccion `editor.setData( e.params.data.qte_presentation);` le asigna el valor al `ckeditor qte_terms` es decir al que se declaro de ultimo y esta en segundo lugar en el formulario.

```
editor.setData( e.params.data.qte_presentation);
```

es la instruccion adecuada, pero como identifico el `editor` al que le quiero asignarle el valor?

Answer (score 0):

En la [documentacion presentada por CKeditor](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_editor-classic_classiceditor-ClassicEditor.html#static-function-create) en el metodo `ClassicEditor.create()`, pienso que, hay una ambiguedad con le nombre del objeto y el nombre del elemento del DOM.

la solucion es esta:

En la definicion del objeto

```
//editor qte_presentation
.then( editor => {
    window.editorPresentation = editor;
} )

//editor qte_terms
.then( editor => {
    window.editorTerms = editor;
} )
```

y para asignar el valor

```
    editorPresentation.setData(e.params.data.qte_presentation);
    editorTerms.setData(e.params.data.qte_terms);
```